# GDM Won't Automatically Start After Boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, xorg, gdm

Ubuntu 10.04

Hi guys.  I'm not sure why but quite recently, my ubuntu desktop started bringing up the command prompt login screen after booting. I want GDM to start up by default.

I can manually bring up GDM by typing:

```
sudo service gdm start
```

or

```
sudo /usr/sbin/gdm
```

but I want something more permanent.

The contents of /etc/X11/default-display-manager point to /usr/sbin/gdm

The chkconfig status for GDM shows that it's off on all run levels... could that be it?  I tried running:

```
sudo chkconfig --add gdm
```

and just got errors...

Any ideas?  How can I get GDM to automatically come up again? Any/all help is appreciated!

-M

---

**Update 1:** I've tried running dpkg-reconfigure gdm but nothing seems to happen and it just returns me to the prompt (no errors).

**Update 2:** If I press CTRL-ALT-F7 at the command login prompt, I see what appears to be the linux boot-up console output.  I noticed the following lines at the bottom:

** (gdm-binary:1256): WARNING **: Failed to acquire org.gnome.DisplayManager
** (gdm-binary:1256): WARNING **: Could not acquire name; bailing out.

I think this is the cause of the problem but I'm not sure what it means. I'm going to try uninstalling and reinstalling GDM.

**Update 3:** I uninstalled gdm (apt-get remove gdm) and reinstalled it (apt-get install gdm).  That seemed to address the errors in update #2 but it still won't start automatically on it's own. As a temporary workaround, I also added /usr/sbin/gdm & to /etc/rc.local and that seemed to start it... but I dunno... seems a bit "unclean".

I don't know if its helpful or not, but I have a tri-monitor system (one nVidia 9400 and one integrated nvidia mobo video) -- all monitors are on a separate xscreen.  There are no issues with displays when I manually start GDM.

Comment: What errors does `sudo chkconfig --add gdm` give?

Comment: @Jawa it goes by to fast but the bottom part says "The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs"

Comment: @Mikey Even my system (Ubuntu 10.04) doesn't have gdm enabled for any of the runlevels, but it still comes up automatically...

Comment: Thanks @kartikmohta I guess I'm looking in the wrong place then... where else should I check for why it's not automatically starting?

Comment: Ok, what does "quite recently" mean, then? Did the symptoms appear after an update? Was the system updated to 10.04 from 9.10 or full (re)install?

Comment: @Jawa I wish I knew.  The only recent changes I made were installing desklets (which I uninstalled).  That being said, the problem did seem to start when I booted the computer with the monitors powered down -- is xorg tempermental about that stuff?  This is a fresh installation of 10.04.

Comment: @Mikey Do you have the gdm.conf in /etc/init? Ubuntu uses the upstart system instead of the old sysvinit boot system, so enabling on runlevels is really not the way it's done I guess...

Comment: @kartikmohta Yup. I sure do. I included some of the excerpts of it below. Let me know if I should look for someting specific.

Answer (score 3):

Trying to fix broken package depedencies by running `apt-get -f install gdm` might fix the situation, if the system is updated from a previous version (<= 9.10).

As Ubuntu 10.04 uses Upstart (`/etc/init`) in place of InitV's scripts (`/etc/init.d`), you should check the contents of `/etc/init/gdm.conf`. It should list the appropriate runlevels when to start GDM e.g. `start on runlevel 5`.

Comment: This is a fresh install.  In the gdm.conf file I see "start on (filesystem and started dbus and (graphics-device-added fb0 PRIMARY_DEVICE_DISPLAY=1 or drm-device-added card0 PRIMARY_DEVICE_FOR_DISPLAY=1)"   

Does that mean that it's not finding the rights conditions for starting?

Comment: Right, it wasn't so simple, forgot about the other conditions... Yes, it seems to me that not all conditions are met, but I don't know how to see which. Maybe logs in `/var/log/gdm/` say something?

Comment: On my Intel integrated graphics touchscreen with Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, after an apt-get upgrade, gdm won't start anymore. `sudo less /var/log/gdm/:0-slave.log` shows 3 lines, the first being `gdm-session-worker[1040]: GLIB-GObject-CRITICAL: g_value_get_boolean: assertion 'G_VALUE_HOLDS_BOOLEAN (value)' failed`.

Comment: I rebooted and still ended up at a blank black screen with an undecorated terminal window in the upper left corner. Alt+F1 to login at a text console and `sudo ps x |grep gdm` show gdm-binary, gdm-simple-slave, and X auth gdm aotaIM or something, and gdm-session-worker running, so i have a different question.